# Regex to replace part of a query string with literals

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have a slight problem in that I am passing several SQL Server `Like` queries (which I don't have control over) in my .Net application and I need to escape some of the characters to make them literals for the database.

For example, suppose the field I am trying to query looks something like:

`This_is [a] long_text field with [literal] characters in it`

And my query looks something like this:

`SELECT * FROM [MyTable] where [MyField] Like 'This_% [literal]%'`

Now, this **should** get that data, the challenge is that the `_` and `[` characters are not seen by SQL Server as the literal characters, so I have to update my query to:

`SELECT * FROM [MyTable] where [MyField] Like 'This[_]% [[]literal]%'`

And then it works.

---

So, my question is that I would like to write a VB.Net function that uses RegEx to find the `Like` part of the statement and then to replace the characters.

Something along the lines of:

```
Public Function ConvertQuery(strSQL as string)

... Some kind of Regex that searches for the word "Like" 
    and then takes everytihng between the 2 "'" characters
    Then replaces the "_" with "[_]" and "[" with "[[]"

Return ChangedString
End Function
```

I know I am giving REALLY bad details, I know what i want, I just can't figure out how to do it with RegEx.

ALSO, if there is a smarter way to do this with SQL Server `Like` statments, **please** also let me know!!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that `C#` tag, I assume you are OK with an answer in C#.

```
string input = "This_is [a] long_text field with [literal] characters in it";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[_\[]","[$0]");
```

**EDIT**

```
string input = "SELECT * FROM [MyTable] where [MyField] Like 'This_% [literal]'";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=Like[ ]*\'.+?)[_\[]", "[$0]");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. How would I go about making it different so it only makes the chanegto the part of the string **after** the word `Like` and between the 2 `'` characters since that's the only part of the SQL that would need to be changed. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help with this. One final question. I had some code AFTER the `Like ' ... '` statement and so I updated the Regex to `(?<=Like[ ]*\'.+?)[_\[](?=.*\')` so as to only limit it to what's between the `'` characters... It works perfectly, but I just wanted your expert opinion - Did I do that correctly or is there a better way to only capture what's between the two `'` characters?? Thank you SOO much!!!

Comment: DARN IT, @L.B, can I ask you for help one more time... When I have 2 compound like statements such as `where [a] like '...' and [b] not like '...'`, the Regex fails... How can I fix it to ONLY work between the `'` following the `like` until only the very next `'` following... Sorry about this...

Comment: Maybe you can use a different approach `var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"Like[ ]*\'(.*?%.+?)\'", m=>Regex.Replace(m.Groups[1].Value,@"[_\[]","[$0]"));`

Comment: Thanks a WHOLE LOT!!!! - My Final output (after your masterpiece) `Regex.Replace(strSQL, "(?<=Like[ ]*\')(.*?)(?=\')",Function(m) Regex.Replace(m.Groups(1).Value, "[_\[]", "[$0]"))`